# phpMyAdmin port needs to be changed

Tags: apache-2.4, phpmyadmin

Sorry this question must have been answered before but none solved my problem. I am in limbo right now. I have developed a website in Django which I want to run on port 80 while I want to run phpMyAdmin on some other port, let's say 8181.

1. My first question is, if it is even possible to change phpMyAdmin's port?
2. If yes, which file will I have to change? `/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` or `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` or `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`?

Your response will help me a lot to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

IF you refer to phpmyadmin accessed through Apache HTTPD, of course you can.

Use the `Listen` directive like for example:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8181
```

Listen tells Apache to use an interface or several (depending on the ip) and the specific ports you tell it.

Then make sure the virtualhost you define to access phpmyadmin is defined like:

```
<VirtualHost *:8181>
```

VirtualHost makes use or become available using the ip and port/s you have defined in Listen.

Comment: This exactly. phpMyAdmin is just another web application so the port it uses is configured with your webserver, not with phpMyAdmin itself.